# IIS: Cookieless session-id encoded as url parameter instead of middle of the url?

Tags: iis, iis-7, configuration

When IIS (7.5) is set to store the session-id cookieless, it stores it in the middle of the url like this:

```
http://yourserver/folder/(S(0nbx3kusz4pfjvq0bu3ab4zo))/default.aspx
```

Is it possible to change this behaviour so that the session ID is stored as an url parameter? 
It should look like this:

```
http://yourserver/folder/default.aspx?sessionId=0nbx3kusz4pfjvq0bu3ab4zo
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: [No](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Long Answer:

It is theoretically possible to change how ASP.NET cookieless support works but you would end up requiring a new bunch of new HTTP modules and have to handle response URL rewriting.  All in all not pretty.  All in all you would end up recreating the session mechanism if you wanted to override the built-in provider.

BTW: StackOverflow has the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595728/asp-net-cookieless-sessionid-url-location).